# Dealing with the results from an overflowed shift with no overflow flag

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm trying to implement a small subroutine which will return words with their bits rotated over N positions to the left inside the [RAR Filter VM language](http://blog.cmpxchg8b.com/2012/09/fun-with-constrained-programming.html), which bears a striking resemblence to x86, and for all intents and purposes can be thought of as x86 with "no extensions".

The piece of code I'm trying to replicate (part of the 'Theta' step of the newly standardized SHA-3 standard Keccak)

`(((x) << (y)) | ((x) >> (64 - (y))))`

Seems simple enough, however the RAR VM uses 32 bit wide registers but the small routine I need to implement can be supplied a 64-bit value.

What is the most natural way to "overflow" the results of `shl` or `shr` into another register so I can reconstruct the x << y and x >> 64 - y? As the title denotes, I do not have access to an overflow flag.

Note: Here's a sample of some code from the assembler so you can see what instructions I have to work with. https://gist.github.com/581f7e162eebd652ee4b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
edx = hi_word
eax = lo_word
ecx = shift_count

if (ecx>32) {
   ecx-=32;
   swap eax,edx
}
simultaneously: edx = edx >> ecx | (eax << (32-ecx))
                eax = eax >> eax | (edx << (32-ecx))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Here's the assembly if you're interested https://gist.github.com/3967018

Comment: I'm glad you found the bug (ecx >= 32). A minor optimization would be if ((ebx=(32-ecx))<0) { eax=hi_word;edx=lo_word; ecx-=32; ebx+=32; } else { eax=lo_word;edx=hi_word;}

Comment: Turns out, this algorithm is described in HAKMEM anyway. Live and learn :)